# how can i get date from datepicker(dialogbox) to toast

Tags: android, android-layout

```
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alram);
            dialog.setTitle("remember me");

            DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
            dialog.show();
            datepicker.getYear();
            datepicker.getMonth();
            datepicker.getDayOfMonth();

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonok);
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
```

what should i give in toast to display the date which i selected in dialog box(datepicker)

Comment: Make DatePicker as final, String tmp = datePicker.getDayOfMonth()+" "+datePicker.getMonth()+" "+datePicker.getYear(); Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tmp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: `datepicker.getYear();
            datepicker.getMonth();
            datepicker.getDayOfMonth();` get value of these in `public void onClick(View v)` method and display it using Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

in your code
 for initialisation

```
  DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
```

for toast

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, day+"/"+month+"/"+year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This is not a dialog.

Comment: means am not getting you brother

Answer (score 0):

activity_main :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.egitim.MainActivity" >

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DatePicker datepicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        datepicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
                int month = datepicker.getMonth() + 1;
                int year = datepicker.getYear();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        day + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```